# Spring Integration test - request Timeout MockMvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing, mockmvc

I am trying to write some integrations tests, and I want to introduce a timeout exception in one case. So, my question is, how can I introduce a delay in the `mockMvc.perfrom` method?

I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076113/mockrestserviceserver-simulate-backend-timeout-in-integration-test)  but it's not suitable to MockMvc.

Any hint?
Thanks in advance.

```
MockMvc mockMvc;

...

@Test
public void timeoutExpirationRequest_shouldReturn500AndFailureBody() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(
            get("/dcsk/9999")
                .accept(parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .header("*****", "*****")
            )
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", not(empty())))
            .andExpect(content().json(load("/expected_result/timeout_expiration.json")));
}
```

Comment: did you make it?